# No Input File Specified with Nested Docroot

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have the following nginx config for 2 different domains:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @route;
    }

    location @route {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 x64 droplet using ServerPilot as my control panel.

The default docroot for ServerPilot apps is:

```
/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/APPNAME/public
```

On one domain, where I'm using the default docroot, this nginx config works fine, but on the other app, my actual document root is:

```
/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/public
```

On this I've changed the root directive as appropriate, but all I get is the `No input file specified.` error.

I've checked permissions, checked my pool permission, and checked that the file exists.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

Changed the config to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /public/ break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png) { }

    location /public {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting my index.php as expected, but no css, js, or images, and clicking links takes me to a 404.

So I'm getting close but still missing something.

UPDATE

From error log I can see why routes are failing. Routes are being requested with an additional trailing slash here:

```
2015/04/29 11:16:06 [error] 9796#0: *7 open()
"/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/public//common/css&css=50d5d2cdd10873f535b8f87c3c65e908" 
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, 
server: my.domain.com, request: "GET /common/css&css=50d5d2cdd10873f535b8f87c3c65e908 HTTP/1.1", 
host: "my.domain.com", 
referrer: "http://my.domain.com/"
```

And for images, they aren't being routed through the public/ directory:

```
2015/04/29 11:16:06 [error] 9796#0: 
*11 open() "/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/image/cache/data/blog/post/landscape-b-40x30h.jpg" 
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, 
server: my.domain.com, request: "GET /image/cache/data/blog/post/landscape-b-40x30h.jpg HTTP/1.1", 
host: "my.domain.com", referrer: "http://my.domain.com/"
```

UPDATE:

After tons of research and looking at other server blocks for different apps I've come up with this, but it's still missing something.

```
upstream backend {
    server unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location /public {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_route_=$args;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
    }
}
```

The only problem left is that every php page returns the home page.

Links work in that clicking them changes the dom history, but the same page loads for each request.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: No errors in the error log.

Comment: Neither in nginx or PHP-FPM error log? How have you configured logging?

Comment: Why aren't you using `try_files`?

Comment: Well I was originally, but it wasn't working so I switched it up. Posting errors in question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location /asset {
        rewrite ^/asset/(.*)$ /public/asset/$1 break;
    }

    location /image {
        rewrite ^/image/(.*)$ /public/image/$1 break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
    }

    location @front {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }
}
```

Thanks for nothing.